# No rights to view anything in /home

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

My `/home` partition was located on my SSD drive but was too small. I wanted to move it my HDD. During the process I somehow lost the ability to acces files on `/home`. Now I cannot find or launch any programs.

I was following this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving 
I performed all steps untill "Copy /home to the New Partition": `sudo rsync -aXS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.` But this tried to copy my `/home` to the SSD which was already full. This step thus failed and I had no acces anymore. I tried to remove the added lines in the fstab file and run `sudo mount -a` again, but this had no effect.

- How can I obtain acces again without re-installing Ubuntu?

permissions can be found here: [image: permissions]

Comment: Re-installing Ubuntu is unlikely to help. You need to learn about file ownership and permissions. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-104-5/index.html) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for a couple of introductory tutorials. If you continue to have help, post another question with more details, such as the ownership and permissions on the `/home` and `/home/{yourhomedir}` directories and on files in your own home directory.

Comment: Can you check the permissions of the /home folder? login with root `sudo su` and type `ls -lah`. It's possible that the owner or the permissions of the folder and the files in it have changed.

Answer (score 0):

To change the permissions, try

```
sudo chown -R (username) /home
```

which will give you full read/write access `/home`. However, your home folder is probably `/home/(username)`, not just `/home`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my HDD had literaly 0 space left. After clearing the trash all programms launched, also I can acces everything as before.